# Signed int from bitset<n>

Tags: c++, c++11, bitset

How can I convert given bitset of a length N *(where `0 < N < 64`)* to signed int. For instance, given:

```
std::bitset<13> b("1111111101100");
```

I would like to get back the value -20, not 8172.

My approach:

```
int t = (static_cast<int>(b.to_ullong()));
if(t > pow(2, 13)/2)
    t -= pow(2, 13);
```

Is there a more generic way to approach this?

**Edit:** Also the bitset is actually `std::bitset<64>` and the N can be run-time known value passed by other means.

Comment: And does it work as intended?

Comment: It does, but as you can see it's not really clear what does it do. So my question actually is, is there "cleaner" way to do it?

Comment: Signed int contains in majority of implementations  less bits of information than bitset with length 64 so your conversion has to be lossy.

Comment: You should use an integer with at least 64 bit, e.g. `int64_t`. There is no problem with signs because you stated that the length N will be smaller than 64,

Comment: @ÖöTiib theoretically there could occur 64bit number but in 99% cases number is smaller then 20bits (13 is most common). So actually I didn't test all cases.

Answer (score 0):

We can write a function template to do this for us:

```
template <size_t N, class = std::enable_if_t<(N > 0 && N < 64)>
int64_t as_signed(const std::bitset<N>& b)
{
    int64_t v = b.to_ullong(); // safe since we know N < 64
    return b[N-1] ? ((1LL << N) - v) : v;
}
```

Comment: Shia LaBeouf is that you :). This won't work. Counterexample: `std::bitset<63> bs(std::string("1111111101100"));` (13 bit signed number) will be 8172 instead of -20.

Comment: @carobnodrvo Didn't realize that was what you wanted, edited that into your question and changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps best is to let compiler to sign-extend it itself:

```
struct S { int64_t x:N; } s;
int64_t result = s.x = b.to_ullong();
```

Compiler likely optimizes that `s` out.

It must be is safe since the `int64_t` (where available) is required to be two's complement.

**Edit:** When the actual bit count to extend is only known run-time then most portable algorithm is with mask:

```
// Do this if bits above position N in b may be are not zero to clear those.
int64_t x = b.to_ullong() & ((1ULL << N) - 1);
// Otherwise just 
int64_t x = b.to_ullong();

int64_t const mask = 1ULL << (N - 1);
int64_t result = (x ^ mask) - mask;
```

A slightly faster but less portable method with dynamic bit counts is with bit shifts (works when architecture has signed arithmetic right shift):

```
int const shift = 64 - N;
int64_t result = ((int64_t)b.to_ullong() << shift) >> shift;
```

Comment: But `N` is known only at run time.

Comment: If N is known only at runtime then 'std::bitset<N>' does not compile so your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, so I set N to be 64 so it cover all possible cases.

Comment: Added algorithms for that case as well.